# Can't install firebase tools on Windows ver 10, npm WARN deprecated

Tags: node.js, windows, firebase

[Command Line Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvxjD.png)

I'm trying to install firebase tools for a project I am doing in React but I keep getting this npm deprecated status. I've uninstalled and reinstalled node and edited paths in environmental variables to point to `C:\Program Files\nodejs`, but nothing is fixing the issue. I'm begging for help at this point because i've looked at nearly every forum.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by doing `npm get prefix` and copying the path into the environmental variables path (advanced system settings > environmental variables > underneath system variables select PATH > edit > paste path > OK). I then did `firebase login --interactive` and it worked.